# issue with qsort in c

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, qsort

I have a structure like this :

```
typedef struct item{
    char label[10];
    int support;
};
```

I created an array of such structures like this :

```
struct item* finstr = (struct item*)malloc(sizeof(struct item)*10);
```

I filled the array with appropriate values and want to sort the array according to the values of 'support', using the qsort function. But, the array is not getting sorted at all. The output is coming out to be the same as input.

here is the call to the qsort function and the code for the 'comparator' function :

```
qsort((void*)finstr,(sizeof(finstr)/sizeof(finstr[0])),sizeof(finstr[0]),comparator);
```

comparator function :

```
int comparator(const void* i1,const void* i2) {
    int l = ((struct item*)i1)->support;
    int r = ((struct item*)i2)->support;
    return l-r;
}
```

I do not understand where I am making the mistake. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sizeof(finstr)` is the size of the pointer `finstr`, not the amount of memory that the pointer is referencing.

Comment: Also that first typedef shouldn't compile imo (it lacks a name)

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Don't use subtraction (L-R) trick in compare. You may get problems when L is big positive and R big negative number. Result can be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `(sizeof(finstr)/sizeof(finstr[0]))` does not give you the number of elements unless `finstr` is an array. In your case, it evaluates to `sizeof(void*)/sizeof(struct item)`, which is most likely `0`.

Replace it with `10`.

Excellent advice from @ForhadAhmed:

> Its good practice to replace the `10` in `malloc(sizeof(struct item)*10)` and the size of the array passed to the `qsort` function with a macro or a variable so that you don't accidentally call `qsort` with a different sized array than what you intended.

Comment: Its good practice to replace the '10' in 'malloc(sizeof(struct item)*10)' and the size of the array passed to the `qsort` function (as suggested in the corection above) with a macro or a variable so that you don't accidentally call qsort with a different sized array than what you intended

Answer (score 0):

Try building and running the following, to see what answer you get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char bar[123];
    int baz;
} foo;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    foo *foo_ptr = malloc(sizeof(foo) * 1000);
    fprintf(stdout, "%zu\n", sizeof(foo_ptr));
    fprintf(stdout, "%zu\n", sizeof(foo_ptr[0]));
    free(foo_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Depending on architecture, you may notice that `sizeof(foo_ptr)` is eight bytes — the size of the `foo` pointer called `foo_ptr`. Compare this with the value of `sizeof(foo_ptr[0])`. This should provide a hint at what is wrong.